# The more you add hours to a DateTime class the more time you loss

Tags: c#, date, time

I have problem with [DateTime.AddHours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addhours?view=netframework-4.7.2) method in C#. I have noticed that the more hours I add to a certain date/time. The more days/hours I lose. For example:

```
DateTime DateOne = DateTime.Now;;
DateTime DateTwo = DateOne.AddHours(438000); // 50 years
```

I add 50 years in hours to DateOne class so i should get 3/10/2069.

However, if you print `DateOne` you will get: 3/10/2019 which is the current date
,but if you print `DateTwo` you will get: 2/25/2069.
That's over 10 days lost within 50 years change.

There has to be something wrong. What exactly I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the impact of leap years over 50 years. You should lose approximately 12 days in this calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Use `AddYears(50)` for add years.

Hours:

```
438000 = 50 * 365 * 24
```

> In the Gregorian calendar, each leap year has 366 days instead of 365, by extending February to 29 days rather than the common 28.

More: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year

Comment: Thanks  I had to educate my self on the Georgian calendar and the leap years. I always though if February was 29 days that means other month gonna be minus 1 day somehow lol.